# Java Generics difference between T and ? extends T

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

**it works.**

method declaration

```
<T> Session<T> start(Criteria<T> criteria, List<Property<T>> orders);
```

usage

```
Criteria<? extends Product> criteria = Utils.getCriteria();
Session<? extends Product> session = null;
session = Service.start(criteria, null);
```

**it doesn't work.**

method declaration

```
<T> List<Session<T>> start(Criteria<T> criteria, List<Property<T>> orders)
```

usage

```
Criteria<? extends Product> criteria = Utils.getCriteria();
List<Session<? extends Product>> sessions = null;
sessions = Service.start(criteria, null);
```

error message

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Session<capture#2-of ? extends Product>> to List<Session<? extends Product>>
```

**if I change method declaration to this, it works.**

```
<T> List<Session<? extends T>> start(Criteria<? extends T> criteria, List<Property<? extends T>> orders)
```

**why doen't this method declaration work?**

```
<T> List<Session<T>> start(Criteria<T> criteria, List<Property<T>> orders)
```

Comment: Is your method declaration same as what you have in your code? A `Criteria<? extends T>` cannot accept a `List<Criteria<? extends Product>>`.

Comment: My bad, the codes was not same as what I have. I modified the codes.

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `criteria` too.

Comment: I modified the codes.

Comment: @JudgeMental has already given the answer to the question. You can also go [through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19219635/1679863) [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18194956/1679863) to understand in deep how multi-level wildcards actually work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what's happening:  you are calling `start()` with actual parameters that are of wildcard type `? extends Product`, so the compiler infers that type, substituting in a capture variable like `CAP#2` for the `?`, for `T` in the call to start.  The type coming out is therefore of the type `List< Session< CAP#2 > >`, where all we know is that `CAP#2 is-a Product`.

You are trying to assign that result to a variable of type `List< Session< ? extends Product > >`, which represents a heterogeneous list of Sessions.  I bet if you assigned it to a variable of type `List< ? extends Session< ? extends Product > >` it would work.

The rule is this:

```
( ∀S : S is-a T ) G< S > is-a G< ? extends T >                       [1]
```

So:

```
( ∀S : S is-a T ) Session< S > is-a Session< ? extends T >           [2]
```

In particular, since `CAP#2 is-a Product`, from [2] we get:

```
Session< CAP#2 > is-a Session< ? extends Product >                   [3]
```

but:

```
List< Session< CAP#2 > > is-NOT-a List< Session< ? extends Product > >
```

However, from [1] and [3] we get:

```
List< Session< CAP#2 > > is-a List< ? extends Session< ? extends Product > >
```

Anyway I recommend the following declaration to be the most generous to your clients:

```
< T > List< Session< T > > start(
    Criteria< ? extends T > criteria,
    List< ? extends Property< ? extends T > > orders
)
```

Comment: Nice explanation about the inheritance relationship between various instantiations. +1