# Generic method vs wildcard - compilation error

Tags: java, generics

I had a issue where (to simplify):

```
public void method(List<List<?>> list){...}
```

gave me a compilation error when called with:

```
method(new ArrayList<List<String>>()); // This line gives the error
```

After reading a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547372), I understood that it would work if I were to rewrite the method signature as:

```
public void method(List<? extends List<?>> list){...}
```

Now, my question is, why does the following work then?

```
public <T> void method(List<List<T>> list){...}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics ? , E and T what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008241/java-generics-e-and-t-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: @Nambari That is not really a duplicate.

Comment: @RohitJain: I will remove it if required, but accepted answer there covers everything related to Generics (AFAIK). OP posted answer below is from one of the references.

Comment: @Nambari Yes, the accepted answer does give links to all the good tutorials and references on generics, but it doesn't specifically talk about multi-level wildcards, which is what OP's case is.

Comment: related: [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confusions do come when you deal with multi-level wildcard syntax. Let's understand what those types exactly mean in there:

- `List<List<?>>` is a *concrete parameterized type*. It is a *heterogenous collection* of different types of `List<E>`. Since `List<?>` represent a family of all the instantiation of `List`, you can't really pass an `ArrayList<List<String>>` to `List<List<?>>`. Because, nothing stops you from adding a `List<Integer>` to it inside the method, and that will crash at runtime, had compiler allowed it.
- `List<? extends List<?>>` is a *wildcard parameterized type*. It represents a family of different types of `List<E>`. Basically, it might be a `List<ArrayList<String>>`, `List<LinkedList<Date>>`, so on. It can be a list of any type that extend from a `List<?>`. So, it will be safe to pass a `ArrayList<List<String>>` to it, the reason being, you won't be allowed to add anything,  but `null` to the list. Adding anything to the list will be a compile time error.
- As for `List<List<T>>`, it is again a *concrete parameterized type*. And since you're dealing with a generic method now, the type parameter will be inferred to be the type that is passed for it. So, for an `ArrayList<List<String>>`, type `T` will be inferred as `T`. A generic method deals with the types that are declared with it. So, there is only a single type `T` here. All the lists you get out of `List<List<T>>` will certainly be a `List<T>` for any type `T`. So, it's a *homogenous collection* of that type of `List`. Inside the method, you can not add any arbitrary `List<E>` to the `List<List<T>>`, because the compiler doesn't know whether that type `E` is compatible with `T` or not. So, it is safe invocation.

---

**Related:**

- [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745/1679863)
- [Java HashMap nested generics with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19219635/1679863)
- [What are multi-level wild cards? Confusion in syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18194956/1679863)
- [When to use generic methods and when to use wild-card?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18176594/1679863)

Comment: @PaulBellora You're right. I've edited the answer a bit. Now it's fine. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  Sorry, @PaulBellora.  I am deleting my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer in [Angelika Langer's generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ302B), "Case Study #3":

> If a method signature uses multi-level wildcard types then there is always a difference between the generic method signature and the wildcard version of it. Here is an example.  Assume there is a generic type  Box and we need to declare a method that takes a list of boxes.
>
> Example (of a method with a type parameter):

```
public static  <T> void print1( List <Box<T>> list) { 
  for (Box<T> box : list) { 
    System.out.println(box); 
   } 
}
```

> Example (of method with wildcards):

```
public static void print2( List <Box<?>> list) { 
  for (Box<?> box : list) { 
    System.out.println(box); 
  } 
}
```

> Both methods are perfectly well behaved methods, but they are not equivalent.  The generic version requires a homogenous list of boxes of the same type.  The wildcard version accepts a heterogenous list of boxes of different type.  This becomes visible when the two  print methods are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The basic reason is that `List<List<?>>` is not a superclass of `List<List<String>>`.

A `List<List<?>>` could contain a `List<Integer>` and a `List<String>` for example.

The generic types must match exactly, otherwise you could get erroneous assignments made.